# Writing 3 Dimension text on image

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

Is it possible to write 3D text on image. I am using asp.net with c#. If possible then kindly give me some Idea.

here is my method to write text on image

private readonly string _textOnImage = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["textOnImage"];
 private readonly int _opacity = Int32.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["opicity"]);
 private readonly int _red = Int32.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["red"]);
 private readonly int _green = Int32.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["green"]);
 private readonly int _blue = Int32.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["blue"]);
 private int _fontSize = Int32.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["fontSize"]);
 private readonly String _fontName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["fontName"];

private bool _havException { get; set; }
 private string _exceptionMessage { get; set; }
 private Bitmap SourceImage { get; set; }
 private Bitmap DestinationImage { get; set; }
 public ImageMethods()
 {
    _havException = false;
    _exceptionMessage = string.Empty;
 }

`public void AddWatermarkText(Image img, String TextOnImage)
    {
        TextOnImage = TextOnImage ?? _textOnImage;

        try
        {
            var lobFromImage = Graphics.FromImage(img);
            FindFontSize(lobFromImage, img, TextOnImage);
            var lobFont = new Font(_fontName, _fontSize, FontStyle.Regular);


            var lintTextHw = lobFromImage.MeasureString(TextOnImage, lobFont);
            var lintTextOnImageWidth = (int)lintTextHw.Width;
            var lintTextOnImageHeight = (int)lintTextHw.Height;

            var lobSolidBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(_opacity, Color.FromArgb(_red, _green, _blue)));

            var posLeft = (img.Width - lintTextOnImageWidth) / 2;
            posLeft = posLeft > 0 ? posLeft : 5;
            var lobPoint = new Point(posLeft, (img.Height / 2) - (lintTextOnImageHeight / 2));

            //  var lobPoint = new Point(RandomNumber(0, img.Width - lintTextOnImageWidth), RandomNumber(0, img.Height - lintTextOnImageHeight));
            lobFromImage.DrawString(TextOnImage, lobFont, lobSolidBrush, lobPoint, StringFormat.GenericTypographic);

            lobFromImage.Dispose();
            lobSolidBrush.Dispose();
            lobFont.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _havException = true;
            _exceptionMessage = ex.Message;
        }
        return;
    }
    private void FindFontSize(Graphics lobGraphics, Image lobImage ,String textOnImage )
    {
        var lobFont = new Font(_fontName, _fontSize, FontStyle.Regular);
        var lintTextHw = lobGraphics.MeasureString(textOnImage, lobFont);
        var lintTextOnImageWidth = (int)lintTextHw.Width;
        var lintImageWidth = lobImage.Width ;
        while (lintImageWidth < lintTextOnImageWidth)
        {
            lobFont = new Font(_fontName, _fontSize--, FontStyle.Regular);
            lintTextOnImageWidth = (int)lobGraphics.MeasureString(textOnImage, lobFont).Width;
        }
    }`

Comment: I have put my code which write simple text on image. how can i convert the text into 3D

Comment: With "draw manually", I meant that you should actually **draw** figures on it that represent text. The `DrawString` method cannot do 3D text.

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is possible, but you'll have to draw it manually.

Please refer to [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/nl/csharpgeneral/thread/960c9c33-1870-4e28-b187-d0a56cb3028d) to get started drawing on an image.

Next, explore the [System.Drawing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.aspx) namespace, in particular the [Graphics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.aspx) class that has draw methods and is used in the above-mentioned post too.

Comment: @krshekhar I don't think you understand, I don't think there is a way to actually write 3D text. One technique to do it is to use double outlined text.

Comment: can you provide me some example for it.

Comment: @krshekhar I'm sorry, I can't, there's no conventional way of doing what you want...

Answer (score 0):

[image: 3d text]

[image]

I found a great article regrading it [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42529/Outline-Text).

Although, the author is using `e.Graphics` mostly inside of `OnPaint(...)` event. But you can create your own graphics as well something like:

```cs
var image = Image.FromFile(path);
// or
var image = Image.FromStream(stream);
// or
var width = 100;
var height= 100;
var image = new Bitmap(width, height);

var graphics = Graphics.FromBitmap(image);
```

and do the rest like in article explained.